# how to rotate an image in two direction with two different angle?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an raw image, I want to perform rotation in two direction with two different angles (which is shown as below).

If css transformation can be simply added as rotateZ(90deg) and rotateY(180deg), I would get the what I want.

```
div{
    transform: rotateZ(90deg) rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this transformation?

[FromRawToTarget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/go4ft.png)

Comment: yes you can achive wht you want 
transform: rotatez(20deg) rotatex(50deg);

Comment: thanks, M Hamza Javed, I succeeded by using "transform: rotatez(90deg) rotatex(180deg); "

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to experiment with css rotate and skew property to get rotation in two direction. You can test in http://css3generator.com with transform.